# Split-string java return value

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

I'm looking for a way to realise the following problem.

Starting from a String a I try to return a String[] equals

```
new String[]{Q},{ec.Qh},{ec.Q2}
```

Does anyone have any sugestions?

So far:

```
    String a="Q={{ec.Qh}{ec.Q2}}";

    int index_first = a.indexOf("="); 
    String name= a.substring(0,index_first); 
    String temp=a.substring(index_first+1, a.length());
    temp=temp.replaceAll("\\{\\{","");
    temp=temp.replaceAll("\\}\\{","\\,");
    temp=temp.replaceAll("\\}\\}","");
    String[] synonyms=temp.split(",");

    //for(int i =0;i<synonyms.length;i++){System.out.println(synonyms[i]);}

    String[] result=new String[]{name,synonyms} // does not work!
```

Comment: Your question is not clear.. what exactly are you trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
String s = "Q={{ec.Qh}{ec.Q2}}";
String[] parts = s.split("(=\\{\\{|}\\{|}})");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
```

prints

```
[Q, ec.Qh, ec.Q2]
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a StringTokenizer thus:

```
new StringTokenizer(string, "{}")
```

Note that the StringTokenizer splits on the nominated characters (`}` and `{`) and *doesn't* return these. You should iterate through the tokenizer results using `nextToken()` and add the results to a `List<String>`.

It's useful here because of its simplicity but the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) notes that `StringTokenizer` is a legacy class, so you should use with discretion.